# how to see the generating select of an sql view on Mysql or phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, select, view, phpmyadmin

I have a view on a Mysql database. I work with it using phpMyAdmin.
I need to see the select statement that builds up this query. Unfortunately I cannot have access to the database files (i know the query is stored there).
I need to find a way, using phpMyAdmin or an SQL statement, that allow me to see the select statement that is inside the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this information in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database, e.g. -

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'view_name';
```

Also, try visual object editors or Object Viewer to view/edit views in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (free express edition).

Answer (score 0):

Try the sql query:

`SHOW CREATE TABLE blah;`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html